# Poco logger does not append logs to existing log file on process restart

Tags: c++, poco

I am using poco logger for my project. I want to have a behavior that if process restarts, poco does not create a new logging file. Below it my configurations: What am I doing wrong? I find that on every restart, poco overwrites the logs instead of appending to previous ones.

```
AutoPtr<FileChannel> pFile(new FileChannel(logfile));
pFile->setProperty("rotateOnOpen","true");
pFile->setProperty("rotation","1 M");
pFile->setProperty("archive", "timestamp");
pFile->setProperty("compress", "true");
pFile->setProperty("purgeAge", "1 months");
AutoPtr<Formatter> pformatter(new PatternFormatter("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %s: %t"));
pformatter->setProperty("times","local");
AutoPtr<Channel> pformattingchannel(new FormattingChannel(pformatter,pFile));
Logger::root().setChannel(pformattingchannel);
Logger::root().setLevel(Poco::Message::PRIO_INFORMATION);
```

Answer (score 2):

You specifically ask to rotate log file on open:

```
pFile->setProperty("rotateOnOpen","true");
```

[Documentation](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.FileChannel.html) states:

> The rotateOnOpen property specifies whether an existing log file should be rotated (and archived) when the channel is opened. Valid values are:
>
> - true: The log file is rotated (and archived) when the channel is opened.
> - false: Log messages will be appended to an existing log file, if it exists (unless other conditions for a rotation are met). This is the default.